# How to know if an empty struct var is filled in Golang?

Tags: go

In Python I can do something like this:

```
aModel = None
models = somefunction()
for model in models:
    if model.cool is False and model.somenumber > -5:
        aModel = model
        break

if aModel:
    print("We found a model we like!!")
```

I'm trying to do the same thing in Golang. After initialization, a variable of some struct already IS a struct and already HAS values though (such as `false` for a `bool` var, and `0` for an `int` var).

So considering the following code:

```
type SomeModel struct {
    cool bool
    somenumber int
}

func main() {

    somemodels = somefunction()

    var aModel SomeModel
    for _, v := range somemodels {
        fmt.Println(v)
        if (v.cool == false && v.somenumber > -5) {
            aModel = v
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(aModel)
}
```

If this prints out `{false 0}`, how can I know whether this is a model I found in the slice, or if it's the default model I set before the loop?

I can of course set another variable like `foundamodel := false` and set that to true if I found something, but that doesn't really seem like the obvious way to go.

Or is it in Go?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pointer instead of a concrete value:

```
var aModel *SomeModel
for _, v := range somemodels {
    fmt.Println(v)
    if v.cool == false && v.somenumber > -5 {
        aModel = &v
        break
    }
}
if aModel != nil {
    fmt.Println(*aModel)
}
```